# On a complex matrix $A$ such that $A A^T$ is real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a complex invertible $n\times n$ matrix such that $A A^T$ is a real matrix.
Does that imply that $A^T A$ is a real matrix too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try (eg.) the matrix $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} i & 0 \\ i & 1  \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: +1 Nice example. This matrix is in the form of $RD$ where $R$ is real and $D$ is a diagonal matrix such that $d_{kk}\in\{1,i\}$ for each $k$.